# Is this a scenario where an exception thrown by a try block can be swallowed?

Tags: java

I have a `try` block like so:

```
Exception thrownException = null;
try {
  puke(); // throws Exception
} catch (final Exception everything) {
  thrownException = everything;
  // do some other stuff, wrapped in try/catch blocks to prevent accidental shadowing
  // now throw the thing
  throw everything;
} finally {
  if (thrownException != null) {
    // do some other work here, taking care to swallow/log exceptions that might come up
  }
}
```

My impression is that the `everything` `Exception` will be thrown, and callers of the method in which this construct exists will see it.

We have a test in place where this does not seem to be the case (i.e. only various log messages hint to us that an exceptional condition was encountered; the `everything` `Exception` effectively disappears from existence).  If we're right, this would seem to be a major bug in JDK 8, so I have my doubts.

What am I missing?

Comment: As shown, the exception will be thrown. We'll need more details to help you diagnose the problem. Preferably a [mcve]. It's quite unlikely you're being bit by a Java bug.

Comment: I tried to turn this into a complete program, and it worked correctly. We need a failing example.

Comment: One way this can happen is your finally block throws some other exception. You should make your actual code look more like your example by taking out the complicated bits one by one and seeing if you get the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, it turns out to be pilot error as I had hoped.  Paraphrased and long story short, my colleague was looking at the wrong log file.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @pvg: Indeed; the finally block takes _great_ pains to avoid this very case.